# find command search pattern

Tags: linux, shell, unix, find

I have below 4 files

```
a_ROLLBACK2to3__test.sql,
a_1to2__test.sql,
a_2to3__test.sql,
a_2to2__test.sql
```

I want to write a `find` command to return the files `a_1to2__test.sql`, `a_2to3__test.sql` and `a_2to2__test.sql`, the file `a_ROLLBACK2to3__test.sql` should not be included in the search.

my find command looks like

```
find . -name "*_*to*__*.sql"
```

but this returns all files but I don’t want `a_ROLLBACK2to3__test.sql`.

basically the files with `ROLLBACK` after the first `_` should not be included..

Can anyone help me to write the search pattern for my requirement?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Simply filter the results with grep:

`find . -name '*_*to*__*.sql' | grep -v ROLLBACK`

Or use the AND clause `-a` with negation `!`:

`find . -name '*_*to*__*.sql' -a ! -name '*ROLLBACK*'`

Comment: +1 for `-a ! -name '*ROLLBACK*'`, which has several benefits over piping to grep.

Comment: Like the `-a ! -name '*ROLLBACK*'` part.

Comment: `-a` is not needed, `-not` has higher precedence than `-and` in `find` and there is already an implied `-a` between every test and action.

Comment: @BroSlow - Good point.  Somehow it never occurred to me that there's an implied `-a`.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply look for the underscore followed by a digit:

```
find . -name '*_[0-9]*to*__*.sql'
```

or for an underscore not followed by R:

```
find . -name '*_[!R]*to*__*.sql'
```